# getting error about string indices must be integers

Tags: python, pymongo, export-to-csv

I am getting the error message : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 10, in 
TypeError: string indices must be integers . please help me.

the python 2.7 script sample:

```
import csv
cursor = db.job_templates.find( {}, {'_id': 1, 'rangePercents.questionnaire': 1, 'rangePercents.termMap': 1})
with open('range_percent1.csv', 'wt') as outfile:
    fields = ['_id', 'questionnaire', 'termMap']    
    write = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fields)
    write.writeheader()
    for x in cursor:
        x_id = x['_id']
        for y in x['rangePercents']:
            z = {
                '_id': x_id,
                'rangePercents.questionnaire': y['questionnaire'],
                'rangePercents.termMap': y['termMap']}                               
            write.writerow(z)
```

the data sample is

```
"_id": ObjectID("51dc52fec0d988a9547b5201"),
 "rangePercents": {
        "termMap": 0,
        "questionnaire": 100
    }
```

Comment: Please include the full error trace when posting, it typically points right at the problem.

Comment: The `y`s in `for y in x['rangePercents']:` are strings, but you are trying to access them like dictionaries

Comment: the error is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't iterate over `x['rangePercents']`, you already can access everything in it through `x`. If you iterate like you're doing, you just get each key of your dictionary as `y`, which is a string and thus why you get your error. Try this:

```
for x in cursor:
    x_id = x['_id']
    y = x['rangePercents']
    z = {
         '_id': x_id,
         'rangePercents.questionnaire': y['questionnaire'],
         'rangePercents.termMap': y['termMap']}                               
    write.writerow(z)
```

Comment: It worked. I like your changes. It is awesome! That is the best solution when export json file to CSV from Mongodb. Thanks so much.